# How to maintain order of methods of interface in implemented class

Tags: eclipse

Suppose I am having below interface inside binary jar:

```
public interface OrderDemo
{
            public void add();
            public void shut();
            public void manage();
}
```

When I am adding this as Jar as part of dependency in my project in eclipse after implementing OrderDemo interface order of method get changed.

```
    public class Demo implements OrderDemo
    {
           @Override
           public void add();
           {
           }
           @Override
           public void manage()
           {
           }
           @Override
           public void shut()
           {
           }
    }
```

Tried option given in eclipse preference but won't work.

Comment: What option are you referring to?